# Randomize border-colors of "DIV" in jquery from PHP while loop

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

how do I randomize border-color of divs I have after running a while loop because when I got and used this

```
<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
var array = ["orange", "blue", "black", "yellow", "green"];               
var colorNumber = Math.round((Math.random() * (array.length - 1)));          
$(".booty").css('border-color', array[colorNumber]);
//$('h1').css("color", colors[rand]);
});
</script>
```

and used it to randomize

```
<div class="media booty">

</div
```

I get the same border-colors [image: The result] instead of the first div, blue then the next div black, then the next div green, please how do I go about solving this.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Don't use `Math.round` when trying to generate a random number within a range of an array - otherwise, it might round *up* to the length of the array, and accessing that index would result in `undefined`. Use `Math.floor` instead.

You'll need to generate a new random color each time you iterate, otherwise they'll all be the same:

```js
const colors = ["orange", "blue", "black", "yellow", "green"];               
$(".booty").each((_, div) => {
  const colorNumber = Math.floor((Math.random() * (colors.length)));          
  $(div).css('border-color', colors[colorNumber]);
});
```

```css
.media {
  border: 1px solid;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="media booty">text</div>
<div class="media booty">text</div>
<div class="media booty">text</div>
<div class="media booty">text</div>
```